# Logs are overriding with new date and log file data is getting overrides

Tags: java, log4j

Log files are getting overrides. And the log files names are chaining with a new date.

In log folder file data is getting changed and yesterday log is changing to today log.

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, stdout, file, INFO, ERROR, FATAL, WARN

# Redirect log messages to console
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

# Redirect log messages to a log file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
#outputs to Tomcat home
log4j.appender.file.File=/home/Test/app.log
log4j.appender.file.File=c:/testLogs/app.log
log4j.appender.file.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
log4j.appender.file.Append=true
```

Comment: o ... kay? and your point is? that's how logging is supposed to work. the active log file contains the logs of the current day. for older logs, look at the file with that specific date in the timestamp

Comment: log4j.appender.FILE.Append=false it slove my problem